# z index of children of different divs

Tags: html, css

im having trouble with some z-index stuff

lets say i have the following

```
<div id="A"> z-index = 2
   <div id="B"></div> 
</div>

<div id="C"> z-index = 1
   <div id="D"></div>
</div>
```

I want "D" to be on top of "B"

of course this is just an example, i know if i swap the z-index of A and C ill get what i ask, but obviously is far more complex than this, but the essence is this, given the circumstances that i post, how can i make so that D is on top of B??

please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve that without changing the `z-index` of A and C.

The way stacking context works in CSS is that when a new stacking context is created (by setting a z-index and either positioning the element, or setting the opacity < 1), it is limited by its parent or descendent’s stacking context. That is, if C has a lower `z-index` value than its sibling A, any descendants of C can not be higher than A or its descendants. It is like A is infinitely higher than C, so even if D has `z-index` of `1000000000`, it wouldn't be as high as C.

You can think of it as sections of a book, where 1.10 is before 2.1, as is 1.10000.

Comment: yeah, that's what i supposed, and is there any way to achieve what i want? javascript or something?

Comment: Without changing the z-index of A and C via JS, I don't even think that can fix it, as that is just the way stacking contexts work in CSS. Is there a reason why C has to have a lower z-index than A, and D has to be its child? You could make D a sibling of A and C, and then set its z-index to 3.

Comment: im hiding content with masks, so, whole content of A has to mask whole content of C, but only D has to be on top of B